# How to set already selected value (Update form) in dynamic dropdown Django template

Tags: python, django, dynamic, django-templates

In django template I am showing dropdown like this . My all dropdown attribute names are in variable `event_dropdown`. And I am assigning like this code

```
<select  name="event_value" >
             <option value="">---------</option>
                 {% for event in event_dropdown %}
             <option value="{{ event.id }}">{{ event.name }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
         </select>
```

Now Issue is In Update case How I can show my already selected value here ? As All things are in for loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can add the `selected` attribute to the value that is already selected, like:

```
<select  name="event_value" >
    <option value="">---------</option>
    {% for event in event_dropdown %}
    <option value="{{ event.id }}"{% if event.id == selected_id %}selected{% endif %}>
        {{ event.name }}
    </option>
    {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

Where `selected_id` is the `id` of the element.

In case there can be multiple selected `id`s, we can make a list or set of the `selected_ids`, and then work with:

```
<select  name="event_value" >
    <option value="">---------</option>
    {% for event in event_dropdown %}
    <option value="{{ event.id }}"{% if event.id in selected_ids %}selected{% endif %}>
        {{ event.name }}
    </option>
    {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

Comment: selected Id is what I want to selected by default ?

Comment: @gamer: given I understood your problem correctly, yes. It is the **`id`** of what you want to select.

Comment: worked like charm <3 never knew we can do that kind of stuff in template . Can I have  any useful resource to get more info about this techniques ?

Comment: @gamer: this briefly covers the subject: https://www.webforefront.com/django/formcustomfieldsandwidgets.html but I do not immediately have an article in mind that discusses this in depth.